# Is it necessary to have Lyapunov function to equal to zero at the origin for the stability?

Tags: nonlinear-system, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Majority of nonlinear control textbooks state the following theorem:

[image]

It explicitly states that the Lyapunov function $V(\cdot)$ must be zero at the origin and positive elsewhere, yet I came across some people state that the value at the origin doesn't matter. For example,

$$
V(x_1,x_2) = x^2_1+x^2_2-1
$$
is valid Lyapunov function. My question is which one is right? Could you please also cite some reference?

Comment: As far as I know, the usual definition is the one you gave.
I don't know why someone would want to remove the condition that the value at the equilibrium point be $0$, since all you'd have to do is add a constant to make it so.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, I would like to know if it is necessary to have this condition.